# Mondrian cache is used when it shouldn't

Tags: mdx, pentaho, data-warehouse, olap, mondrian

I have a problem with what it seems to be Mondrian's cache. I have this query:

```
SELECT
{ [Measures].[Searches] } ON COLUMNS,
{ [Date.Date].[2014].[4].[4] , [Date.Date].[2014].[4].[3] } ON ROWS
FROM [Searches]
```

that returns:

```
                       [Measures].[Searches]
[Date].[2014].[4].[4]           463
[Date].[2014].[4].[3]           381
```

what is correct. But if I do this query before the above one:

```
WITH
SET [TopCombinations] AS TOPCOUNT([Tags Group.Tag Group Combinations].[Combination].Members, 5000, [Measures].[Searches])
SELECT
{ [Measures].[Searches] } ON COLUMNS,
{ Filter( {[TopCombinations] }, [Measures].Searches > 5 ) } ON ROWS
FROM [Searches]
WHERE ( [Date.Date].[2014].[4].[4] )
```

when I do the first query, it returns a different result:

```
                       [Measures].[Searches]
[Date].[2014].[4].[4]           2,061
[Date].[2014].[4].[3]           381
```

It seems that when the Topcount query is done, some cache is made. After that the other query uses cached data and returns a different value. Any thoughts on what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: You should report this to our Jira tracker (jira.pentaho.com). I think this is a known issue which was fixed in the latest release. File the bug report and we'll look at it. Make sure to include the version number you've been using.

Comment: I updated to the last release (3.7) and oddly this is still happening.